# insert statement not writing to db file in sqlite 3?

Tags: php, sqlite, insert

I'm trying to write data from a simple form to an SQLite database, but even though I'm committing the transactions, nothing is written to the database file. This is the php code:

```
$expense = new Model();
$expense->add_expense($_POST);
```

and in the Model class:

```
class Model {

    private $database = 'expenses.db';
    private $dbh;

    function __construct() {
        $this->dbh = new PDO('sqlite:/var/www/expenses/' . $this->database);
        $this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    }

    public function add_expense($args) {
        $stmt = $this->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `expenses` (`type`, `name`, `location`, `receipt_date`, `price`, `notes`) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)');
        $this->dbh->beginTransaction();
        $stmt->execute(array_values($args));
        $this->dbh->commit();     
    }
}
```

This is the contents of `$args`, from inside the function:

```
Array
(
    [type] => type
    [name] => item_name
    [location] => place
    [date] => 1313180040
    [price] => 8.86
    [notes] => none
)
```

Also, `$stmt->getMessage();` doesn't output anything. This is the SQL to create the table:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;
CREATE TABLE expenses (notes TEXT, type TEXT, location TEXT, name TEXT, price NUMERIC, receipt_date NUMERIC);
COMMIT;
```

Validation isn't relevant, so I left it out. The contents of `$args` that I listed is after validation occurs, and it's all correct.

UPDATE: Same code but using bindParam and named parameters instead:

```
$stmt = $this->dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO `expenses` (`type`, `name`, `location`, `receipt_date`, `price`, `notes`) VALUES (:type, :name, :location, :receipt_date, :price, :notes)');
```

and the binding statements:

```
$stmt->bindParam(':type', $args['type']);
$stmt->bindParam(':name', $args['name']);
$stmt->bindParam(':location', $args['location']);
$stmt->bindParam(':receipt_date', $args['date']);
$stmt->bindParam(':price', $args['price']);
$stmt->bindParam(':notes', $args['notes']);
$stmt->execute();
```

Still, nothing happens.

Comment: Try adding the following to the constructor: `$this->dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);`. This makes PDO throw exceptions when an error occurs (instead of ignoring it silently as it does by default). It might tell you what's wrong. I have never used transactions in PDO myself.

Comment: I normally use that in my Model constructors, but I completely forgot it this time. No exception is thrown, though. I don't know if it's related, but when I try to open the database with `sqlite expenses.db` (when I'm /var/www/expenses) I get an error message of `Unable to open database "expenses.db": file is encrypted or is not a database`

Comment: What happens when you bind the parameters individually with `$stmt->bindParam()`? I don't know if it's significant but all examples that I found online use PDO::exec() rather than PDOStatement::execute() with beginTransaction() and commit().

Comment: I haven't found anything that says prepared statements and execute _can't_ be used within a transaction, but even when I remove the two lines of transactional code, nothing happens. I added code with binding named parameters, too, if that helps. I fixed the problem of opening the db from the command line: I was using `sqlite` instead of `sqlite3`. I recreated the database using the `sqlite3` command and recreated the table, but nothing happens.

Comment: I'm afraid I'm out of ideas. I ran your original code on Windows with the following array as $_POST: `array('type' => 'type', 'name' => 'name', 'location' => 'place', 'receipt_date' => 12345, 'price' => 15.00, 'notes' => 'none')` and the record was inserted.

Comment: Solved it; The command `sqlite3 expenses.db` created the database with my linux user account as the owner, but the php script runs through the web server, so the owner is www-data. I changed the ownership and permissions, and it's working fine now. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it; The command sqlite3 expenses.db created the database with my linux user account as the owner, but the php script runs through the web server, so the owner is www-data. I changed the ownership and permissions, and it's working fine now. Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

but even the command line sqlite3 has problems with owner script to owner db writes:
viz: sqlite>  INSERT INTO author (name) VALUES ('Hugh MacDairmid');
only after opening the terminal with su ( or using sudo ) did the db writes occur.
I suppose this should not be a surprise.